# gpg trustdb.gpg loading

Tags: gnupg

I have a problem in using gpg on linux boot up (Debian).

I have a process that is being loaded on bootup using `rc.local`. This process will call `gpg` verify API's using `gpgme`. I found out that by running the process manually `gpg` works fine, while when the process is loaded using `rc.local` gpg doesn't work. (`rc.local` runs on boot up.) I get no keys on boot up when I try:

```
gpg --list-keys
```

I am guessing that the `rc.local` is being called before loading the keys (`trustdb.gpg`). Do you know where in the kernal on boot up we load the public gpg keys?

Comment: I guess when you start it using `rc.local`, `gpg` is run under another user with another home directory. Try running `gpg` with the correct user or specify the GPG home directory manually.

Answer (score 0):

Is your script in rc.local running have the proper permissions (ie, is it su'ing to a user other than the one who has rights to read the gpg db?)  Root will of course always have access, but when a gpg db is created it is always on a user specific level, so if that user does not have access, it will not work.  As a comment above states, su to the proper user, and specify gpg home dir:

```
su user

gpg --homedir ~/.gnupg.userkeyring
```